# Is there a way to choose and open a text file from a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, linear-search

I'm currently writing a program that displays a set of guitar chords in TAB using turtle and I was wondering to save me writing out many nested if statements, if it would instead be possible to instead use text files with the numerical data inside and then store the names of the text files in a dictionary in python like so:

```
d = {0: "", 1: "Am.txt", 2: "Bm.txt", 3: "Cm.txt", 4: "Dm.txt", 5: "Em.txt", 6: "Fm.txt", 7: "Gm.txt"}
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

My aim was to then use a sequential search to identify which test file to open based off of the user input using this:

```
n = 0
penup()
T.color('white')
x = 0

while x != 1: # this while loop is redundant
    N = 0
    chord = int(input("Please choose a number for your chord"))
    # compare input with dictionary values
    while N != 2:
        if(chord == l[n]):
            f = open(d[n])
            while True:
                N2 = f.readline()
                if not N2:
                    break
        if(chord != l[n]):
            n = n + 1
    
        N = N + 1
    x = x + 1
```

My code past this is just the commands telling the turtle how to move and write the text from the file with N2.
So far my result has just been printing "Am.txt" instead of the content in that text file with no error messages following it. My previous code to this was to just manually write out everything with if statements but that seemed needless to me if I could make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are new to coding? The benefit of dictonaries is that you can directly access the `values` by their `keys`. Also be careful with `while True` loops, as they create infinite loops...
Also in your case the user needs to know which number is what chord. Why not make the `keys` more specific. Also read about opening and reading files.
Try this for now, but be aware you have to be in the directory where the `Am.txt` and `Bm.txt` are located (absolute vs relative path).

```
d = {0: "", 'Am': "Am.txt", 'Bm': 'Bm.txt'}


while True:
    chord = input('Input Chord: ')
    if chord in d:
        with open(d[chord], 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            print(line)
    else:
        print('chord not found')
```

Comment: I am not too new to coding but I am pretty new to trying to use open(). I wasn't sure how much code to show in the post as I'm pretty new to stack overflow, but essentially I made a graphic with turtle that displays all of the chords with a number beside them starting from 1. I also made sure that everything is in the same file too. 

So with what you've posted above this would eliminate my nested loop but still let me repeat multiple times over if I am grasping this correctly?

Comment: Yes it will run until you close it manually and you can basically just type in your chords like `Am`. If the chord is not in the dict it will simply wait for a new entry. For the `open()` statement, if you use the `with open()` statement this will ensure that the file gets closed after you are done.